# Creating a Macro to transfer only certain data from one worksheet to another that meets a criteria

Tags: vba, excel

So I need to create a macro that transfers data in specific cells in a column on worksheet 1 to worksheet 2 based on data in a different column in worksheet 1 that meets a specific criteria. Say Worksheet 1 had a column(A) with colors Blue or Green and another column(B) with Apples or Pears (Apples to Blue and Pears to Green). I need to create a macro that will only transfer the Apples that correspond to the color Blue to another column in Worksheet 2.

```
Sub Update()
  Dim c As Range
  Dim j As Integer
  Dim Source As Worksheet
  Dim Target As Worksheet

    ' Change worksheet designations as needed
    Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet 2")
    Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    j = 1     ' Start copying to row 1 in target sheet
    For Each c In Source.Range("D35:D100")   
        If c = "Blue" Then
           Target.Range("C5").Value = Source.Range("B35")
           j = j + 1


        End If
    Next c

End Sub
```

No matter what I try I cannot get it to only transfer the data that meets the criteria of "Blue". Any help would be greatly appreciated please and thanks!

Comment: `If (c = "Blue"  and c.offset(0,1) = "Apples") or (c = "Green"  and c.offset(0,1) = "Pears") Then`  where the `1` in the `Offsets` is the number of columns to the right from column D.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you wanted to copy this into Column C of your target worksheet...

```
Sub Update()
  Dim c As Range
  Dim j As Long
  Dim Source As Worksheet
  Dim Target As Worksheet

' Change worksheet designations as needed
Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet 2")
Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

j = 1     ' Start copying to row 1 in target sheet
For Each c In Source.Range("D35:D100")   
    If (c.Value = "Blue" And c.Offset(0.1).Value) = "Apples" Or _ 
(c.Value = "Green" And c.Offset(0,1).Value = "Pears") Then
       Target.Range("C" & j).Value = c.Value
       j = j + 1

    End If
Next c
```

End Sub